# IllegalArgumentException from creating a NotificationChannel

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-channel

Very occasionally, we're getting an IllegalArgumentException with an empty localized message on some devices while creating a notification channel. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072959/creating-a-notificationchannel-throws-an-illegalargumentexception) answer, but the channel name is 100% certain not "", so not the issue in this case. It's working for almost all users, but sometimes this exception is thrown for a user. We cannot seem to link it to a device type or specific Android version either.

The code for creating the channel:

```
public void createNotificationChannel(String label, String description, int importance) {
    // Create the NotificationChannel only on API 26+
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(label, label, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

The stack trace of the exception:

```
android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2078)
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1990)
android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.createNotificationChannels(INotificationManager.java:3205)
android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannels(NotificationManager.java:713)
android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager.java:701)
```

Anyone has any ideas? I'd love to fix this issue!

Answer (score -1):

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Configure the notification channel
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{500, 500, 500, 500});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
```

Try this piece of channel code. It is working code.

Comment: Hi Ammad, thanks for thinking along, but this is exactly what happens in my code (except for the lights, color, vibration pattern and vibration methods). The error is thrown on `createNotificationChannel` in some rare cases